# Unit test neo4j with TestNG - newImpermanentDatabase

Tags: neo4j, testng

When I want to create GraphDatabaseService in setUp() method as below:

```java
      private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

      @BeforeMethod
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
      }
```

I get error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.autoCreatePath(Ljava/io/File;)V
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.lock(StoreLocker.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:287)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:227)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase.<init>(ImpermanentGraphDatabase.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(TestGraphDatabaseFactory.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory.newImpermanentDatabase(TestGraphDatabaseFactory.java:36)
    at pl.piotr0123456.neo4j.operations.GraphOperationsTest.setUp(GraphOperationsTest.java:29)
```

As a workaround for this I use:

```java
     graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("target/testGraph/test1");
```

with transaction rollback. But I think this isn't a good solution.

Is it a possible to create for each unit test clean graph in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hoods, ImpermanentGraphDatabase uses `test-data/impermanent-db` (in 1.9.RC2) on the filesystem. You could either

- make sure that `test-data/impermanent-db` has sufficient permissions
- instantiate ImpermanentGraphDatabase directly without the factory: `new org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase(myStoreDirectory)`. `myStoreDirectory` could be a temporary directory for example.

Be aware if you run multiple tests in parallel. In this case you should use the second approach since multiple ImpermanentGraphDatabase instances are not allowed to share the same store directory.

Comment: When I switched neo4j to version 1.9.RC2 and changed setUp() method to graphDb = new ImpermanentGraphDatabase(); 

I get error:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.test.impl.EphemeralFileSystemAbstraction.getFileSize(Ljava/io/File;)J at org.neo4j.kernel.AutoConfigurator.getFileSizeMb(AutoConfigurator.java:175)
 
When I downgraded neo4j to version 1.8.1 tests are green.

Comment: Did you upgrade all Neo4j dependencies to 1.9.RC2?

Comment: now I'm using maven with this dependency:

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
            </dependency>


yes, I was trying <version>1.9.RC2</version>